# How to extract a plugin dll from DB CRm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to extract a Crm 2011 plugin DLL registered in the database. 
Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Even if it is possible, this is considered to be an intellectual property violation.

Comment: @Anwar why? Like with anything you can do with technology there are also legitimate reasons why you want to do this

Comment: @Anwar Not necessarily correct. I've often had to pull out company owned DLLs from a CRM database, because they've either lost the code or maybe can't locate it. I have come across this situation yet again today where a 3rd party consultancy (aka cowboys) came in, did some work, and never bothered to source control the code. So now we have to decompile the DLL to get at the code in order to fix their bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Plugin Extraction Tool was created to assist Dynamics CRM Administrations to extract assemblies that were previously registered in a CRM database as plugins.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ce989f76cdcfaebe%21421)

Comment: Thanks! This was useful as it allowed for the export of plugins that were from a managed solution, which were giving me issues trying to export via the solution method

Answer (score 5):

For CRM 2011 there's a much easier way to achieve this.

- Create a new solution
- Add the Plugin Assembly to the solution
- Export as an unmanaged solution (Zip file on your hard drive)
- Unzip the contents of the Zip File

You can find the DLL in a folder like this:

```
[Unzip Folder]\PluginAssemblies\[DLLName-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]\
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the plugin is stored as a Base64-String which you could extract. 
See for example http://mytechlifedays.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/retrieving-the-plugin-dlls-from-ms-crm-dynamics-database/